# Delete a cache in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I would like to delete a cache defined into my User.model

This is my cache method (into UserModel) :

```
def cached_favgroups
  Rails.cache.fetch([self, "fav_groups"]) {fav_groups.to_a}
end
```

And this is my code to delete it (into GroupController):

```
def something
  expire_fragment(current_user.cache_key+"/fav_groups")
end
```

The code generated with this line is :

```
Cache delete: views/users/1-20171116091341756594/fav_groups
```

Instead of this :

```
Cache delete: users/1-20171116091341756594/fav_groups
```

Do you know how I can change my code to erase the first part of my path (views/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change

```
expire_fragment(current_user.cache_key+"/fav_groups")
```

Into

```
Rails.cache.delete(current_user.cache_key+"/fav_groups")
```